# How we can upload multiple blobs to azure using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload 6 images to azure blob from single endpoint that I get from a registration form. The code shows how to upload a single blob but I need to upload multiple blobs at the same time. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  //var dirname = require('path').dirname(__dirname);
  //var dirname1 = require('path').dirname(dirname);
  var filename = req.files[0].filename;
  var path = req.files[0].path;
  var type = req.files[0].mimetype;
  var options = {
    contentType: type,
    metadata: { fileName: filename }
  }
  blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(containerName, filename, path, options, function (error, result, response) {
    if (error != null) {
      console.log('Azure Full Error: ', error)
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(response);
      var user = new User();
      user.name = req.body.name;
      user.picture = 'https://yourblob.blob.core.windows.net/profile/' + result.name;
      user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.json(err.message);
        }
        else {
          return res.json({ User: user });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just upload them all one at a time in a loop?

Comment: @powerc9000 doing this as its own issues, causing connection errors.

Answer (score 2):

As `Azure Storage for node` sdk is based on RESTful APIs, and we implement upload functionality via [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-blob).

There is no such RESTful API or function in SDK for us to directly upload multiple independent blobs to Azure at once time.

You can implement this functionality for yourself by uploading files in loop.

Comment: doing this as its own issues, causing connection errors.